# All of the answers are great - what to do?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about what to do to improve my language abilities, and many great answers were given. I selected an answer, but the BEST answer would truely be a combination of all of them, since they each bring a great viewpoint, exerience, or suggestion.

Is there a way to combine them?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we are faced with the issue of "all anwers are great, which to accept?" this may be an indication that the question was not a good fit for the site's design.

Only if we followed the StackExchange *One Question - One Answer* maxime we are at our best. Selecting the single best answer from many good or poor answers then is easy. A prerequisite for this is that any question given will also be answerable in a single good answer.

This may have not been the case with your question:

- [Practicing German in daily activity](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13680/practicing-german-in-daily-activity)

There is not and will not be a single "best" approach to this question, and if it were for you it may not be for somebody else visiting the site. So "best" will not only be impossible to say but it will also be highly subjective in this special case.

On most StackExchange sites questions like yours are therefore being quickly closed as "too broad" or "subjective". Now we are a language site where things may be a bit different. We therefore at present sometimes allow such questions when they are interesting enough, or we leave similar questions open for people to be able to add an answer later.

Even though desirable there is no need to "accept" answers but it helps future visitors to pick the best answer, and it will give the user who answered a reward in reputation points. In case you feel there are more than one good answers and did not accept one, the "best" answer will be pushed up by their vote count. Whenever there are more than one upvote on an answer the system counts the question as "answered" irrespect of being "accepted".

Not having accepted an answer yet also indicates that another answer is still welcome.

In case you will get another even better answer after you already had accepted an answer you can unaccept the old answer to then accept the newer, better answer. Keep in mind that this also means you remove 15 reputation points from the user who wrote the first answer.

Last not least it is also good practise to write and accept **your own** answer (you will then not get reputation points of course), where you can summarize things, copy comments, or write something you found later. If you do not wish to gain reputation from other people's postings: make your answer *Community Wiki* on posting.

Comment: Thanks! That question was closed as a duplicate, so I figure I would just accept one. Being a duplicate means there cannot be more answers, correct?

Comment: Yeah - no more answers... but you can answer the linked dupe question (or we can merge answers to your questions there).